# Solving linear systems efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra, external-calls, arbitrary-precision

In certain calculation I encountered a system of linear equations in 144 variables, and it takes hours to compute. Most probably the reason is that coefficients are really huge integers (about $10^{50}$ order of magnitude).

Is there a way to speed it up somehow? Say, call some external routine from matlab, or lapack c library or something like that?

As requested by [Roman](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26598/roman), here is the system:

```
With[{d=11},
 With[{dd=(d+1)^2},
  With[
   {
    x=t^2 (-4+t)^10 (1+t)^5/(256+256 t+3840 t^2+1920 t^3+1440 t^4+236 t^5+t^6)^3+O[t]^dd,
    y=t^5 (-4+t) (1+t)^2/(16+16 t-4 t^5+t^6)^3+O[t]^dd
   },
   Solve[Map[#==0&,CoefficientList[Sum[a[m,n]x^m y^n,{m,0,d},{n,0,d}],t]]
  ]
 ]
]
```

Comment: Have you tried working with high precision reals rather than integers?

Comment: Please post the linear system here so that we can experiment. It's difficult to answer this question abstractly.

Comment: @Roman Done, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system of equation is singular and has a two-dimensional null space that is quick to find.

```
With[{d = 11}, 
  With[{dd = (d + 1)^2}, 
    With[{x = t^2 (-4 + t)^10 (1 + t)^5/(256 + 256 t + 3840 t^2 + 1920 t^3 + 1440 t^4 + 236 t^5 + t^6)^3 + O[t]^dd,
          y = t^5 (-4 + t) (1 + t)^2/(16 + 16 t - 4 t^5 + t^6)^3 + O[t]^dd},
      A = CoefficientList[Sum[a[m, n] x^m y^n, {m, 0, d}, {n, 0, d}], t];
      v = Table[a[m, n], {m, 0, d}, {n, 0, d}] // Flatten;]]]
```

the linear equations are $A=0$ or, equivalently, with

```
M = D[A, {v}];
```

the system of equations is $M\cdot v=0$. That is, the vector $v$ of coefficients (unknowns) must be a linear combination of vectors in the [null-space](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NullSpace.html) of the $144\times144$-matrix $M$:

```
NullSpace[M]
(*    two 144-vectors    *)
```

All of this is very quick to compute. To see what these null-space vectors look like in practice, try studying their normalized form (chopping off small coefficients):

```
N[Normalize /@ NullSpace[M], 100] // N // Chop
(*    {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 6.98999*10^-10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        -1.31459*10^-10, -2.97958*10^-9, 1.49682*10^-6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 3.7335*10^-9, -1.95466*10^-7, -0.0000257353,
        0.00164175, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.55145*10^-10,
        -2.09378*10^-7, -0.00018851, 0, 0.999999},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, -6.63462*10^-10, -5.32768*10^-8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1.54502*10^-8, 1.66909*10^-6, -0.0000694192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 5.32162*10^-8, -0.0000225255, 0.000579073, -0.0454816,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.56214*10^-9, -1.31016*10^-6,
        -0.00108831, 0.998964, 0}}                                  *)
```

Comment: That's wonderful! So then `Solve` does not recognize linear systems at all?

Comment: It does, but may take longer because of some additional checks: try a simple example like `Solve[{a + b == 0, 2 a + 2 b == 0}, {a, b}]`.